# How to compute the derivative of tr$((MAM^{T})^2)$?

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have the following derivation here

[image]

[image]

Where M is a square matrix, [image] is also a square matrix (diagonal). But I do not know why the derivative of [image] is [image].

I only know before that the derivative of tr$(X^2)$ with respect to $X$ is 2$X$ from the matrix cookbook, but I find it no way to deal with [image].

Comment: If $\Psi$ or ($A$) is symmetric, then the solution from Johanachale looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by taking matrix derivative, Let $Y = M \Psi M^\mathrm{T}$ and $J = \text{tr}[( M \Psi M^\mathrm{T})^2]=\text{tr}(Y^2)$, we take derivative w.r.t $Y$ and $M$, respectively,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{d} J &= \mathrm{tr}[\mathrm{d}Y^2 ] \\
&=\mathrm{tr}[(\mathrm{d}Y) Y + Y (\mathrm{d}Y)] \\
&=\mathrm{tr}[(2Y (\mathrm{d}Y)] \\
\end{aligned}
$$
so,

$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial Y} = 2 Y^\mathrm{\mathrm{T}}
$$
and from matrix derivaty, we get,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{d} J &= \mathrm{tr}[\frac{\partial^\mathrm{\mathrm{T}} J}{\partial Y}  \mathrm{d}Y ] \\
&=\mathrm{tr}[\frac{\partial^\mathrm{\mathrm{T}} J}{\partial Y}  \mathrm{d}(M \Psi M^\mathrm{\mathrm{T}}) ] \\
&=\mathrm{tr}[\frac{\partial^\mathrm{\mathrm{T}} J}{\partial Y}  (\mathrm{d}M) \Psi M^\mathrm{\mathrm{T}} + \frac{\partial^\mathrm{T} J}{\partial Y} M \Psi (\mathrm{d}M^\mathrm{T})] \\
&=\mathrm{tr}[\Psi M^\mathrm{T}\frac{\partial^\mathrm{T} J}{\partial Y}  (\mathrm{d}M)  + \frac{\partial^\mathrm{T} J}{\partial Y} M \Psi (\mathrm{d}M^\mathrm{T})] \\
&=\mathrm{tr}[\Psi M^\mathrm{T}\frac{\partial^\mathrm{T} J}{\partial Y}  (\mathrm{d}M)]  + \mathrm{tr}[\frac{\partial^\mathrm{T} J}{\partial Y} M \Psi (\mathrm{d}M^\mathrm{T})] \\
&=\mathrm{tr}[\Psi M^\mathrm{T}\frac{\partial^\mathrm{T} J}{\partial Y}  (\mathrm{d}M)]  + \mathrm{tr}[(\mathrm{d}M)   \Psi M^\mathrm{T} \frac{\partial J}{\partial Y}] \\
&=\mathrm{tr}[\Psi M^\mathrm{T}\frac{\partial^\mathrm{T} J}{\partial Y}  (\mathrm{d}M)]  + \mathrm{tr}[   \Psi M^\mathrm{T} \frac{\partial J}{\partial Y} (\mathrm{d}M)] \\
&=\mathrm{tr}[ (\Psi M^\mathrm{T}\frac{\partial^\mathrm{T} J}{\partial Y}   +   \Psi M^\mathrm{T} \frac{\partial J}{\partial Y} )\mathrm{d}M] \\
\end{aligned}
$$
so,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial J}{\partial M} &= \frac{\partial J}{\partial Y} M \Psi + \frac{\partial^\mathrm{T} J}{\partial Y} M \Psi \\
&= 4(M \Psi M^\mathrm{T}) M \Psi
\end{aligned}
$$